# global string variable interpolation in method

Tags: ruby

i'm trying to create an automation feature/step definition using capybara and cucumber with ruby. the whole intention is to have a dynamic xpath selector like this one:

```
    slector =   "/span[text()=dynamic]"
```

defined with more selectors, out from the methods.
The question is, It is possible to interpolate the variable inside a method?

```
    define_method :foo do |dynamic_value|
      selector ['dynamic'] = #{dynamic_value}
    end
```

or something similar?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not very clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You a make a method like so, it takes an argument which is the dynamic value and builds the selector

```
def build_selector(dynamic_value)
   "/span[text()=#{dynamic_value}]"
end
```

then when it's time to use it you write `selector = build_selector("some-value")`. You can do this last step inside another method, if you've defined the method in a scope that's accessible (you can just define the method on the root scope if you don't know about this).